# Alternatives to mutate & rowwise & grepl

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl, rowwise

I am working on a dataframe like below and want to count the occurrence of some patterns ('B' and 'C') from column A.

The code which uses rowwise, mutate & grepl do work but using rowwise is pretty slow. I am wondering if there are any alternatives to rowwise for getting the same result?

```
temp <- data.frame(
  A = c('A','B','C','BC')
)

temp %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  mutate( B = sum(grepl(pattern = 'B',A),grepl(pattern = 'C',A) ) )
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  A     Count
  <chr> <int>
1 A         0
2 B         1
3 C         1
4 BC        2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grepl` is vectorized, it's your `sum` that is the problem. Use `+` instead:

```
temp %>% 
  mutate( 
    Count = grepl(pattern = 'B', A) + grepl(pattern = 'C', A)
  )
#    A Count
# 1  A     0
# 2  B     1
# 3  C     1
# 4 BC     2
```

It's the same difference as this:

```
sum(1:3,  1:3)
# [1] 12

1:3 + 1:3
# [1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: Thank you Gregor for pointing out the underlying issue!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_count()` from `stringr` as it is vectorized over string and pattern:

```
temp %>%
 mutate(Count = str_count(A, "B|C"))

   A Count
1  A     0
2  B     1
3  C     1
4 BC     2
```

Comment: Thank you tmfmnk! I think yours is a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option with `nchar` and `gsub`

```
nchar(gsub("[^BC]", "", temp$A))
#[1] 0 1 1 2
```